# non-vanishing of a symmetric tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. For any set of nonzero vectors $(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_N )$, we can construct a symmetric tensor

$$ W = \sum_{\sigma\in S_N }v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes v_{\sigma(2)} \cdots \otimes v_{\sigma(N)} . $$

I want to prove that $W\neq 0 $ if the $v$'s are nonzero. The proof I found is as follows. Suppose we have an inner product on $V$. Then consider the inner product of $W$ and the symmetric tensor

$$ S = u \otimes u  \otimes \cdots \otimes u . $$

We have

$$ \langle W | S \rangle = N! \prod_{i=1}^N \langle v_i | u \rangle .  $$

We can definitely find $u$ such that $\langle v_i | u \rangle \neq 0 $ for all $i$. This is by the common knowledge that a vector subspace is not the union of a finite number of proper subspaces.

But can one find a proof without using the inner product?

Comment: Yes---instead of an inner product, pick an appropriate element $\phi_{a_1\cdots a_n}$ of the dual space, $V^*$ and consider the full contraction $\phi_{a_1 \cdots a_n} W^{a_1 \cdots a_n}$. Raising the indices of $\phi$ with the inner product essentially recovers your argument.

Comment: But this is very similar to the inner product approach.

Comment: Yes, that's what the second sentence of my previous comment says. At any rate it avoids introducing/using an inner product.

Comment: A slightly different perspective: under the usual isomorphism to the polynomial ring on $\dim V$ variables, your element goes to $N! v_1 \cdots v_N$. Since the $v_i$ are non-zero, their product is non-zero, so your element is non-zero.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson  Nice. Any reference?

Comment: Any introduction to symmetric tensors in characteristic zero should say this. For instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra#Relationship_with_symmetric_tensors